# Can I use expo packages after expo eject

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have built an app using Expo and now due to some reasons I want to eject the app from expo cli using `expo eject`. Can I still use Expo packages ?

Comment: yup, you can continue using them! they work in expo managed apps and bare react-native apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Expo packages should work. Read more about ejecting Expo here https://docs.expo.io/bare/customizing/

Comment: Just a note for anyone who found this on internet. Expo eject is now called prebuild. But the behavior is still the same. You will be able to continue using expo packages.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use expo packages after expo eject
expo eject does not affect any of your files it just creates android and ios folder